# Equation describing the motion of an object attracted to magnet

Tags: electromagnetism, newtonian-mechanics

Imagine there is a strong magnet at `(0, 0)`. There is a horizontal rail on `y=1` on which a ferromagnetic object rides. The object can only move on the rail. No friction anywhere.

The object starts at `(0, 1)` with some positive velocity.

How will the graph of its movement look like?

Comment: What's the orientation of the magnet?

Comment: @abstract I didn't consider that. I'd be interested in an answer for any kind of orientation.

Comment: @ACuriousMind This is not a homework question! I'm a 28-year-old dude and I'm not in college! It's just something I was interested in.

Comment: @Ali See my message above

Comment: @Bernhard See my message above